# it isn't reading my number inputs in the original class

Tags: java, class, methods, input

My code isn't seeing the input numbers from the second class. It keeps thinking all the inputs are zero so it isn't completing the program. Where did I go wrong?

I've tried a couple different things that I could think of, but it didn't work. It keeps outputting false/unsolvable because all the numbers are zero instead of the inputs.

The second class is just the number inputs.

```
private static int a, b, c, d, e, f;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers for 'a, b, c, d, e, f' ");
    Chapter9_2ndclass c2 = new Chapter9_2ndclass(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    Exercise_09_11 Chapter9_2ndclass = new Exercise_09_11(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    // Exercise_09_11 getY = new Exercise_09_11(a, b, c, d, e, f);
    // //constructors

    if (Chapter9_2ndclass.isSolvable()) {
        Chapter9_2ndclass.getX();
        Chapter9_2ndclass.getY();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unsolvable");
    }

}

public Exercise_09_11(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
}

public boolean isSolvable() {
    double isSolvable = ((a * d) - (b * c));
    System.out.println(isSolvable);
    if (isSolvable != 0) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        System.out.println("The 'isSolvable' number is, " + isSolvable);
        return false;
    }
}

public int getY() {
    int Y = ((a * f) - (e * c)) / ((a * d) - (b * c));
    return Y;
}

public int getX() {
    int X = ((e * d) - (b * f)) / ((a * d) - (b * c));
    return X;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of `Chapter9_2ndclass` and `Exercise_09_11`, and assigning it your `private static int`s through their constructors.

Primitive `int` defaults to `0` when unassigned in this context, hence you get all `0`s.

You probably want to assign them by parsing arguments of the command-line execution as `int` in your `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

All variables are zero because they are not initialized and you passed the variable to the contructor of `Chapter9_2ndclass` and  `Exercise_09_11` which causes default value of int ie `0` to be passed and initializing them to `0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are never reading any input from the user and setting the values. Specifically, the static int declarations a, b, c, d, e, and f default to 0 and are never set.